# Can't figure out how to turn this table into a JSON object

Tags: mysql, json

I have a mySQL query that returns the following table:

```
group_id     groupName          word_id     word
---------    --------------     --------    ------
111          transportation     1           car
111          transportation     2           plane
111          transportation     3           train
222          fruit              4           apple
222          fruit              5           banana
222          fruit              6           pear
```

I'd like to send this data through a function (in PHP) which returns it to my ajax call in this JSON format:

```
{
  "group": {
    "group_id": "222",
    "groupName": "fruit",
    "wordlist": [
      {
        "word": "apple",
        "word_id": "4"
      },
      {
        "word": "banana",
        "word_id": "5"
      },
      {
        "word": "pear",
        "word_id": "6"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am not sure if this query result is ideal for this kind of thing but I can't seem to get my head around another way. I know its kind of lame not to at least take a shot at it and post my result but I'm not very good with arrays yet so this is making my head spin and I don't know where to start. Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: May I throw a suggestion here? How do you get the data? Is it associative array? If so please use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to turn the array into correct JSON. Also Im not sure what format are you trying to achieve? Can you post the desired JSON format you want?

Comment: The JSON format is in my post at the end

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write a custom function. But ultimately you'll use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode).

A few notes about the custom function:

- Create the `wordList` array
- You'll need to wrap the resulting data under a `group`.